# variable in table function is empty when called on other functions

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables, onclick

I am trying to make a jsp project about an attendance monitoring system. I have a table that contains data retrieved through a database, and have added an event once the user clicked on a row. Once it's clicked, the number of participants in the event row selected would appear in a certain div that I made. It worked, however, I cant find a way to accesss the variable in the onclick function for other functions that needs the variable in the row selected.

```
<script>
            var event
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var rows = document.getElementById('table'), rIndex;
                for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
                        event = this.cells[1].innerHTML; //the important variable needed
                        var houseA = "azul";
                        var houseG = "giallo";
                        var houseC = "cahel";
                        var houseR = "roxxo"

                        $("#a").load("dataEvents.jsp", {
                            event,
                            houseName: houseA
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            function diffFunction(){
                alert(event); //returns empty
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling or binding the `diffFunction()` ? Also do not declare variable names like `event`, it will cause problems, because for every javascript function which is being invoked through some events, there is a default implicit variable named `event` available inside the function.

Comment: the diffFunction() is called at the <div> that loads the number of participants from the selected row. And yeah indeed the problem was the event variable. I am fairly new to the whole jsp thing haha. Thank you so much